# User Group Technical Community Proposal

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

I work with our local user group community and have found there is not a good place on the internet for leaders of user group or communities to share and learn from each other.  I have been working on a podcast (http://usergroupradio.com) and a communmity site for community leaders.

I am very interested in the stackoverflow model and would like more information about what is required to create a community site around community leaders.

I think a stack overflow style site where community and user group leaders can come together and ask and answer questions from other user group leaders would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [this "super secret" site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). From the [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> It’s where groups of experts come together to build new Q&A sites that work just like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Be prepared to wait a little while though.

The current model is to roll this out slowly, using people familiar with the way Stack Overflow et al operate to make sure the new sites are a success. That means choosing topics we (the SO user base) know something about.

However, once these are up and running and hopefully attracting new people other sites are more likely to get started as there is a wider community to draw from so there are likely to be more SO experts who also know something about your area of expertise.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53695/how-should-critical-mass-be-calculated/53696#53696) for the explanation from Jeff himself.

Search for questions tagged "[area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51)" to get some more answers on how the system works.