# Display total "Committed" reputation for a proposal

Tags: feature-request, area-51

It looks like the progress during the commitment phase of a site proposal is scored based heavily on the [total reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53695/how-should-critical-mass-be-calculated/53730#53730) for users that have committed to the new site. Right now you can see the total reputation for each individual user, but there is no way to see the total reputation committed to the site proposal.

Any chance this could be displayed somewhere on the proposal page? It would help users understand how much backing a site has better than just the 22% listed in the progress section. Plus it would be cool to see `1.2M total rep` listed for a site!

**Update:** Right after I posted this I found an answer about how exactly [progress is tracked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733) for site proposals. I Initially thought it was based on total reputation, but looks like it is only partially based on reputation. I still think this would be helpful for tracking a site's commitment compared to existing sites. SO for example has [250k users and 44.6M total rep](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/183/user-count-and-total-reputation-for-various-reputation-levels-on-so), but [SF](http://odata.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/187/user-count-and-total-reputation-for-various-reputation-levels-on-su),[SU](http://odata.stackexchange.com/serverfault/s/188/user-count-and-total-reputation-for-various-reputation-levels-on-sf),and [Meta](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/s/189/user-count-and-total-reputation-for-various-reputation-levels-on-meta) have 2.2M to 2.7M total rep and 18k-44k users. This means that the Web Applications site already has around 2-3% of the total reputation from all trilogy sites committed to making it a success (about 1.5-2M committed so far).

Comment: I think it'd end up being misleading/confusing given that the total "score" a user contributes to the percent complete is not scaled linearly based on their reputation. In other words, total rep is not directly equatable to percent complete. Eg (as per the first link you gave): 1 user with 30000 rep (10000 on 3 sites) adds 19.6 to the score, but 30000 users with 1 rep each would add 30000 to the score. So both would have the same total rep, but the first would have a *far* lower percentage complete.

Comment: Sure there is .. add it up :)