# Why did uncommitting from a proposal has it lose 2% commitment progress when my committal only gained it 1%?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51

I have committed [a proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer) yesterday, I noticed its increased 1%

But according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53743/should-we-sympathy-commit-to-a-site-proposal), and Jeff's email, I uncommited today, it went down from 3% to 1%, so it cost -2%

Does it fair?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing it's simply a case of the percentage complete being rounded to the nearest percent when it gets displayed.

Eg. Let's say you're "worth" 1.3% and you commit to the proposal while it's at exactly 1% complete. This will push it up to 2.3%, which will be displayed as 2%. Then as other commiters continue joining, the percentage will keep going up little by little. Lets say it got to 2.7% when you decided to leave, it would have been displayed as 3%, but when you left it would have dropped to 1.4%, which would be displayed as 1% giving the appearance of a 2% drop.

So it just looks like it went up 1% & then down 2%, when it really just went up & down 1.3%.

Comment: also.. *the conspiracy!*

Comment: @Jeff - This is clearly just the plausible sounding yet not quite as satisfying "swamp gas & weather balloons" cover up story, as required for any good conspiracy theory.