# Localized (or foreign language only) Area51 site

Tags: feature-request, area-51, localization

Hi all,

I understand the StackOverflow team is not fond of localized content.

However, what about localized area51 sites ?

As an example, I'm thinkg about requesting a french only DIY house building site, as we have numerous candidates to such projects in our country (yep, even french can come take a look at what happens over the ocean ;-)).

I understand site text may not yet be localized (things like the "questions", "tags", "how to format", "notify" and all other contents that are site globals).

But is it envisionned ?

And if so, will sites like the one I would like to promote be elligible as valid area51 projects ?
(besides, the chosen name for the galaxy of stackoverflow-like sites is totally awesome).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to this question: [Is it OK to have non-English question and answers in area51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area51)

But particularly to @Joel's answer: ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area51/53004#53004))

> Right now, on Area 51, it is OK to propose new sites in other languages. However, remember that right now the language of Area 51 itself  is English, so the title of your proposal should be in English, and your proposal should include the language in which the site will be conducted

...

> Any non-English sites that make it through the commit phase may spend some time in temporary limbo, while we gear up to support it. We don't yet have a localizable user interface, we don't necessarily speak your language, and we haven't debugged things like bidi issues yet. We really want to watch the first batch of new sites closely so we prefer that those sites all be in English. However we are committed to support sites in other languages just as soon as we're confident that the site creation process is working fine.

Comment: Bidi issues should be a nightmare indeed. But I wouldn't bother too much about the localized user interface, at least for the beginning. I think that most people willing to commit have at least a basic grasp of English, and normal users should be able to make a sense of the interface (they just need a "passive knowledge" of English). 
Asking a question and/or giving an answer is quite a different matter, though: this is why a group in another language would be important.