# CSS problem with RTL questions in Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, design, rtl

In [the Persian IT proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer) commitment page, votes and questions are "mixed together". I'm using Chromium 
6.0.453.0 (51332) Ubuntu 10.04, same with Firefox 3.6.6. Like so:

[image: Lines are layed out like this: "30 question-body-here-written-right-to-left votes"]

Comment: Whether or not a language-specific area51 site is a good idea or not is a good question, but a different one.

Comment: Concerning your concern, it's [been](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area-51) [addressed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53958/localized-or-foreign-language-only-area51-site). On the matter of the bug, replicated on FireFox on Windows 7.

Comment: -1. no freehand circles

Comment: @Earlz not to mention freehand arows!

Comment: @Earlz Fixxored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed now, assuming I know how it's supposed to look in RTL languages.