# Discussion using other languages besides English are allowed on Area51 Discussion zone?

Tags: discussion, area-51, internationalization

There are many proposals targeted to audiences of people who don't speak English. They can't discuss using English but they are essential to proposal definition.

Should we use a language specific tag to help filter?

I want to discus merging of my own proposals and others like [Software Development (in Portuguese)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/software-development-in-portuguese) and [Software Testing (in Portuguese)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10120/software-testing-in-portuguese) for example.

Comment: Maybe, first, we should discuss if it makes sense to have non-English SEs in the first place.

Comment: @badp That discussion has been [already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53958/localized-or-foreign-language-only-area51-site) [had](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area-51).

Comment: And answered on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area-51 too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Discussions in Area 51 should follow the same criteria as [conducting *proposals* in other languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area-51/53004#53004).

- The **title and text** of your question must be in English.
  (It is okay to include a translation into the native language after the English text)
- The title should include the language in which the site will be conducted:

> **Should we merge the Software Development and Testing Proposals? (Portuguese)**

- All the answers and comments can then be conducted either English or the native language.

Comment: I think this is not going to go far as long as the UI is not localized. But then, I imagine internationalization would be a *really* huge task, far beyond translating the UI and not to be taken lightly...

Comment: @Pekka: Localization is slowly creeping up in priority but, yes, it's a big undertaking. We have no specific objection to non-English speakers "jumping the gun" a bit but they simply have to understand the restrictions that the menus and prompts will all be in English... for the time being.

Comment: The problem is there is no point in translating the UI if you don't have a team of people that can answer surport questions etc in the langage you translate into.