# Why are Area 51 proposal comments restricted to 150 characters?

Tags: support, area-51

I'm following a proposal in Area 51 and today noticed that the proposal comment max length is 150 characters, which does not make sense to me.

[image]

I'm not sure how recent this change is, but before I left a 384 character long comment.  Today I broke my comment in 3 or 4... despite my intents to be concise.

This reminds me of Twitter... is that a bug?

Comment: Is any down-voter willing to tell me what's wrong with my question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's no longer possible for users to comment on Area 51 proposals; such comments are now called "announcements" and restricted to employees only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Immediately below the comments section, is the discussion area you've previously found.  http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com was added because in proposals, we do want to encourage discussion that is more than just a single thread of comments.

[image: discussion area on proposal]

When this change was made, adding new comments was no longer possible.  However, it was decided that for some extremely simple, one-off comments, creating a discussion question was too heavy.  For that reason, we re-enabled comments, but we still want to encourage actual discussion to take place in the discussion area.

If your comment is something that you are looking to discuss, please create a new discussion for that.  Don't try to cram it in to a comment - and if you are finding yourself separating your comment out like you have done, that is a big hint that perhaps it does not belong in the comment section but rather the discussion section.  **The length limit was lowered specifically to encourage people to use the discussion area for actual discussions.**

Comment: The other day I created a [new discussion in Spanish](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1233), as the proposal is to create a Spanish-spoken site, but I'd been warned to [create the discussion first in English](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76815/76833#76833) which is a bit/lot of more work to do... specially if the interested people will understand and speak Spanish.  On the other hand, with comments, I'm hoping the @mentioned users get a notification about it and come back with answers.