# Continued comments

Tags: discussion, comments

On many different stack exchange sites I often see people using several comments to get a point across because a single comment doesn't provide enough characters for the statements they wish to make.

Does this violate any rules?

If someone can't fit what they want to say in the space of the allocated size of a comment then shouldn't that mean that what they intend to say should not be put in a comment?

If so should those comments be flagged?

Also, if someone down votes this can you please provide a reason why a single comment is limited to 600 characters (or whatever it is)? If comments are intended to be used for making long statements then why put such a limit on the number of characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep in mind that various sites on the SE network may have different local customs as to how comments can legitimately be used on their site.

This being said, I can give the example of SO. There is no hard and fast rule on SO that you cannot break down an extended comment into multiple comments, if you must. It would be a shame if there were a hard and fast rule about this seeing as I've seen really useful comments having to be split into two submissions because, well, the issue was complex enough to necessitate that space but was not such that it should have been posted as a separate answer.

As far as I am concerned, I see the length limitation as a reminder that comments should be short and that they are more easily subject to deletion than actual answers are. First thing to ask myself: should I post this as an answer instead of a comment? If it is not appropriate as an answer, then I do my best to shorten my text to fit into the smaller number of comments submissions as possible, so long as it does not impair the message.

Answer (score 5):

> Does this violate any rules?

No, it doesn't. Although we expect the comments to be directed at the OP and in relation to the post to either get clarification or improvements. Also remember that comments are not meant to float around for ever.

> If someone can't fit what they want to say in the space of the allocated size of a comment then shouldn't that mean that what they intend to say should not be put in a comment?

If the quality of the post or the issue being discussed makes such lenghty or even multiple lengthy comments needed I see no problem with it, as long as it tries to get the post clarified. The system does provide an option after a couple of comments to move the discussion to chat.

> If so should those comments be flagged?

Not necessarily but if the comments are acted upon they are better removed by their user. You can flag if you feel they are too chatty or obsolete, that is the comments don't add any value to the post and without the comments you don't miss any information. Best would be to update the post based on the comments.

> Also, if someone down votes this can you please provide a reason why a single comment is limited to 600 characters (or whatever it is)? If comments are intended to be used for making long statements then why put such a limit on the number of characters?

A limit had to be chosen. When the comments table was designed the 600 char limit seemed reasonable and I feel it still is. See also this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89759/why-is-the-comment-character-limit-140-on-area51-proposals-while-its-600-on-the) that asks about the limits on Area51 and other SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are not intended for making long statements.  You will note that if someone actually uses comments that way, the system will try to redirect them to chat.

I don't know that the solution is flagging the comments though.  If the comments are productive, then they shouldn't be flagged even if they break a technical rule.  It's far better to leave this to the commenter and the poster generally.  Flagging a comment mostly puts it in a delete queue, which is not the place for productive content.