# Is it possible to build a Q&A answer site using SE API which will behave like stack overflow in my native language? (It is Bengali)

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, api

I am not a big organization or something, but I just want to build a site which will behave like stack overflow. I like the way this site is.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It's totally ok to use SE platform as a regular user but not the API.

See other questions about SE sites in languages other than English:

- [Is it OK to have non-English question and answers in Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area-51/53004#53004)
- [Discussion using other languages besides English are allowed on Area51 Discussion zone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76815/discussion-using-other-languages-besides-english-are-allowed-on-area51-discussion)
- [Localized (or foreign language only) Area51 site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53958/localized-or-foreign-language-only-area51-site)
- [Is it OK to have non-English question and answers in Area 51?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area-51)

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Exchange API can't be used in this manner, and there are currently no options for you to run an SE site on your own hardware.

You could try an open source alternative (although I don't know how good it is): [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/).

Comment: Thank you! ineededtoaddmorecharacter

Comment: so just to be clear, you couldn't create a site thats all about say, bunnies, and put it under your own url, and have it act a lot like stackoverflow already does, except maybe with a few modification to make it more useful to rabbit enthusiasts?

Comment: @Not if you wanted it to be run on the Stack exchange software. You're always welcome to build your own, but that wasn't the question.