# StackExchange 2.0 sites in other languages than English?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51

Will there be any StackExchange 2.0 sites on which questions/answers will be written in other languages than English?

I know there will be mixed-language sites, such as sites for people who are learning to speak X. But even on those sites, the main language will be English.

I'm asking whether there will be any fully-localized StackExchange 2.0 sites.

*I'm asking this because I'm developing an application based on the SE API, and so far I've been reluctant to localizing it because all SE sites are in English (so it doesn't make sense to have my app in another language, since it's basically just a SE browser).*

So, is there any policy on this?

**Note:** I've scanned the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and it doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: I've closed this a dupe of another one, that has a more official answer, which now states: *"As of 2015, we are not currently accepting proposals for non-English sites."* . That seems to be the most up-to-date information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are some e.g. [Tamil](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19330/tamil) but they're not really taking off at the moment. Maybe because so much of the surrounding infrastructure is in English, it requires a minimum of English + other language to participate, which significantly lowers the number of potential contributors.

(There's also one for [math in Turkish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17879/matematik) which has an even more limited catchment!)

I think these are the only ones matching your criteria.

The next closest fit is the generic [Languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16613/languages).

**Update:** [Here's another](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20483/derecho-argentino).

[Is there no end to this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20499/recht-oder-unrecht)? =:-)

Comment: You forgot maybe the most important: [Persian IT and Computer](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer)

Comment: @badp - oops, you're right, thanks.

Comment: It's a bit sad that when I click on all these proposals they've been deleted due to inactivity.

Comment: @WendiKidd: It's awesome that these proposals that would [split](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113940/le-proposte-del-tipo-sito-in-lingua-creano-inaccettabili-barriere-linguist?lq=1) the community by [language](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow) have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[Chinese Emigration 移民海外](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36960/chinese-emigration) can nearly launch a simplified chinese site, but it is still waiting for example simplified chinese supportable tag function and the terms such as reputation and badge should be translated to simplified chinese for long time so that it can successfully launch.

[Culture category](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/3/culture?tab=beta) has most probationary sites in other languages, some of them can also have tags in other languages.