# Will there be support for non-English Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, stackexchange-2.0, non-english-speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Le proposte del tipo “<sito> in <lingua>” creano inaccettabili barriere linguistiche e vanno uccise con il massimo pregiudizio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113940/le-proposte-del-tipo-sito-in-lingua-creano-inaccettabili-barriere-linguist)

Will Stack Exchange enable users to start sites in non-english languages? Noting that some languages are Right-to-Left, so it can be quite "not-easy" to have.
I wish this can be available soon (if it's going to happen) as I can imagine many non-English cultures will benefit a lot from Stack Exchange if it's provided in their native language. So, is it going to be provided in non-English languages?

Comment: There are a bunch of Stack Overflow in <Language> proposals on Area 51 already, none of which get very much support.

Comment: @John: How on Earth did you find that?

Comment: @Dennis I remembered the author's name from when I first read that question.

Comment: @John that post made me lol. "English Language and Usage.... In _French_!" ;-)

Comment: What a fantastic idea! As if the community wasn't split enough already among [StackOverflow, Programmers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange), [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/), [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), now we need localized versions to further increase the chances that your question is answered, just... in another language. Soon we'll have a StackApp that will translate new questions into random languages on the off chance that someone answered them in Farsi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already a few non-English proposals on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/):

- [Stack Overflow (in German)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/31024/stack-overflow-in-german) (currently in Commitment)
- [Stack Overflow (In Arabic)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39345/stack-overflow-in-arabic) (currently in Definition)
- [Spanish Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language-usage) (currently in Public Beta)
- [Japanese Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language-usage) (currently in Public Beta)

Note that the `X Language & Usage` sites allow posts in English and the language `X`.

That makes `X Language & Usage` are a great idea, in my opinion, since they treat a unique topic (that language) and they're available to many people (native `X` speakers and everybody who knows English).

The `Stack Overflow in X` sites are still in Commitment or even Definition (far from Public Beta, might never happen). I assume that there is little interest in these sites, since they will ultimately **divide** the Stack Overflow community.

If you need a good answer and you need it fast, the bigger community, the better. Although I'm more fluent in Spanish and German than I am in English, I doubt I'd ever visit SO en Spanish or SO in German, as long as SO in English has the larger community...

Answer (score 1):

[There already are many such sites being proposed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=stack%20overflow)

If the language isn't there, [propose it](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology). Search the site for the language first though. (Assuming you want it in egyptian, [it's not there](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=egyptian)). If you want it in Arabic, [there already is a proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39345/stack-overflow-in-arabic?referrer=LV4zRwgvVgu3GaYuclIOJA2). Consider following it and asking sample questions.

The site will go through three stages. Currently it's in the first, where only example *questions* are allowed to determine on-topicness. IMO, it will be quite a bit of time before it takes off (not much interest it seems), though. Sit tight in the meantime, and try to spread awareness about the site.

Comment: @Dennis that's why i linked to the Arabic one as well. I don't think Egyptian is a language still in use, but wouldn't hurt to add it. By the way, I fixed a mistake in your answer--SOArabic is in definition, not commitment.

Comment: Saw it, thanks. Wikipedia said something about Egyptian Arabic. I don't know what exactly that is, so I withdrew my comment.

Comment: @Dennis I doubt it will _ever_ get that specialised(it seems that that is a dialect). Even Wikipedia has only one Arabic site, IIRC (I used to be part of the small wiki management team on WP, and I've only come across two arabic-script sites--Arabic and Persian). If wikipedia doesn't have it, then neither will we for a loooooong time.

Comment: @Dennis, then again, Wikipedia has [tons of obscure language/dialect wikis in the pipeline](http://incubator.wikimedia.org/wiki/Incubator:Wikis). So maybe that's not the best example. Though the lack of an Egyptian Arabic  proposal on WP does say something about the size of that online community.