# Is it hopeless to start a non-English site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

After some really hard work my (Hungarian language) site is in commit phase. I read all the rules and calculus of getting 100% of commitment and now I find it impossible mission to move to the next phase.

Am I right that it is a complete waste of time to boost commitment, since my members are by definition new users with zero reputation, so my site will never have more than a few percent commitment?

Comment: "*since my members are by definition new users with zero reputation*" Why is that "by definition"? Can't they contribute to some other SE sites? The point of these commitment requirements is to ensure that the initial users are familiar with the way an SE site works.

Comment: http://wolfrevokcats.com/area-51-the-place-where-dreams-die.html <-- there is your answer.

Comment: [It](http://german.stackexchange.com/?as=1) [is](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/?as=1) [not](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/?as=1) [really](http://russian.stackexchange.com/?as=1) [*impossible*...](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/?as=1)

Comment: @phwd That certainly points out important issues, but at the end of the day... while the process isn't without flaws, not all of the difficulties proposals encounter are due to that process. (I would agree that Area 51 Discuss is where Area 51-related discussions go to die, though.)

Comment: What is the site about? If it's about a topic that has a vast majority of users understanding English, then it's a [terrible idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113940/le-proposte-del-tipo-sito-in-lingua-creano-inaccettabili-barriere-linguist) to create a site in any non-English language. The Internet isn't a better place thanks to the diversity of language; [on the contrary](http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/essays/english-universal-language), it unites people of vastly different backgrounds using a common language, and like it or not, that language is English.

Answer (score 8):

This ... depends.

We have several sites about languages ([Russian Language & Usage](http://russian.stackexchange.com), [French Language & Usage](http://french.stackexchange.com), [Japanese Language & Usage](http://japanese.stackexchange.com), and a few others). Those are certainly possible to put through the Area 51 process. If you're thinking of a Hungarian Language & Usage site (I see someone recently [created a proposal for it](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47836/hungarian-language-usage)), then it's theoretically doable. It might be difficult, since the target demographic might be smaller than for the other, more widespread languages, but in principle... it could work. Especially on a large site like Stack Overflow, there may be a group of users who are fluent in Hungarian or want to learn it and would be interested in committing to the proposal.

If you're talking about a fully localized size (such as, Stack Overflow in Hungarian), we don't have support for that just yet at all. We're working on some localization projects (most recently, [support for non-ASCII tags](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/kanji-tags-now-available)), but we're still a ways out from being able to support a fully non-English site.

If you're talking about a site that doesn't need to be fully localized (user interface and all), but would like to be able to post in Hungarian... that could work. I don't think we have any of those just yet (aside from the sites about languages I mentioned above). One potential issue here could be that if your audience is non-English-speaking at all, you would run into big problems with moderation and user experience because the interface will still be in English.

And with all *that* said, we're also working on the [next generation proposal process](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/next-generation-of-area-51) that should address some, if not all, of the core issues with Area 51 while preserving the philosophy that a successful site needs some sort of a base of community support and engagement to start from.