# When will there be a Chinese Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, languages, internationalization

I made a proposal which hit 100% commitment:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36960/chinese-emigration-

but Area 51 said:

> This launch is on hold while we add the international features needed
>   to make it functional for this community. Allowing international
>   characters in tags is our first priority before launch. Dates will be
>   announced when available.

Now it is two months later, and it still has not gone to private beta.

How can I get this done? Maybe you need someone to do some coding? I can help...

Comment: Well, they *do* have an opening... http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/23229/web-developer-q-a-team-stack-exchange

Comment: I hope *never*. It's a [terrible idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113940/le-proposte-del-tipo-sito-in-lingua-creano-inaccettabili-barriere-linguist) to create a StackOverflow clone in any non-English language (note that I'm not a native English speaker either). The Internet isn't a better place thanks to the diversity of language; [on the contrary](http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/essays/english-universal-language), it unites people of vastly different backgrounds using a common language, and like it or not, that language is English.

Comment: @DanDascalescu so do you think unicode is a terrible idea?

Comment: @Tinyfool: I think the part of Unicode supporting non-Latin characters is a backward compatibility layer that we'll use until everyone will get on the English bandwagon, and then to preserve historical information. Until then, some information is really only of use locally, governments are slow to change (i.e. mandating English as another official language), so Unicode will serve that role too.

Comment: @DanDascalescu You said,"Until then, some information is really only of use locally",So you think when all information will be in English ?

Comment: @Tinyfool: I hope that in 100 years over 80% of information in the current use of 80%+ of the human population will be primarily in English.

Comment: @DanDascalescu So at least in 100 year there is the need of other language. And I think you need get a job teach our Chinese speak English. There are 1.4~1.5 billion people in China, most of them can not speak English.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-Chinese-version-of-Stackoverflow-com

Answer (score 15):

See: [Is it hopeless to start a non-English site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156899/is-it-hopeless-to-start-a-non-english-site/156910#156910)

> If you're talking about a fully localized size (such as, Stack Overflow in Hungarian), we don't have support for that just yet at all. We're working on some localization projects (most recently, [support for non-ASCII tags](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/kanji-tags-now-available)), but we're still a ways out from being able to support a fully non-English site.

Short answer is that there's a lot of dev work needed to support localization before we can even start on the task of actually localizing (which is going to be even *more* work) - we're working on tools now that'll allow bilingual folks to help in constructing a site for those who can't really use English effectively at all. This isn't a quick or easy task, but obviously there's considerable demand for it so we're pushing forward as quickly as possible. Remember, we're retrofitting a system that was designed and built only to support English - this has some significant challenges (remember [all those pluralization bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/spell-fix-in-user-profile-1-questions) folks reported?) that we'll probably go into detail on in a future blog post.

Comment: Ah I see, so it's not so much coding more as making sure you have all the giant letters you'd need to bludgeon people with.

Comment: I *can't wait* for the i18n pluralization bugs!

Comment: And also the famous numbering bug which still exists in big companies like Google: `10 thousand` looks correct in Western languages, but not in Eastern languages. (`10千` does not make sense)

Answer (score 2):

On 2015 Tim Post, the Director of Stack Overflow Communities here at Stack Exchange, posted [Internationalization 'State of the Stack](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20988/133145) on Area51.

It looks to me that will take few years to have more international sites but you could help to solve the current issues related to the existing sites by joining the discussion on [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/289691)