# What is the status of support for foreign language SEs?

Tags: discussion, area-51, languages, internationalization

What is the current status of support for launching foreign-language SE sites?

On the Area51 it is stated that:

> This launch is on hold while we add the international features needed
>   to make it functional for this community. Allowing international
>   characters in tags is our first priority before launch. Dates will be
>   announced when available.

However, without details is the unicodization of tags the only thing to do and if it has to be done once or for each SE in details.

My question is, when estimately the foreign language will be launched and are the current preparations to be done once only, or for each language separately?

More in details, makes it sense to make proposal in Polish language, for example? Will running the Turkish site make it possible to run site in Polish (Russian, Chinese etc.) without separate preparations?

Comment: ["Still in progress"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158891/when-will-stackoverflow-subsite-support-chinese)?

Comment: The was a progress counter in SAP deploy application that was progressing in pre-defined speed and stopped at 99%, hanging there even for 10 minutes. I would expect something more sappy here ;)

Comment: My guess is 6-8 weeks.

Comment: From now? and once for all possible languages?

Comment: @lechlukasz I suppose you'd better read up on the [many memes of meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/151015)

Comment: I wish there were some serious answer to that post... It's very discouraging for Area51 community :(

Comment: I wouldn't be discouraged. While it's tempting to start SE clones in non-English languages, ultimately that [divides the community on a silly criterion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113940/150034) (where users were born, basically), instead of uniting them around a common interest (programming, security, or anything else). The Internet isn't a better place thanks to the diversity of language; [on the contrary](http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/essays/english-universal-language), it unites people of vastly different backgrounds using a common language, and that language is English.

Comment: @DanDascalescu It is bad. You can't completely avoid diversity, because there _are_ larger languages as english and it is only the matter of time when they will appear in larger numbers on the net. Maybe a real world language will appear in 200 years of yet later, but if it happens, probably it won't be the english. But if there is localized support to the large non-english languages, smaller languages should also have.