# Will language-specific sites affect the user's contribution to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, area-51, languages, localization

I just stumbled upon the Area51 Stack Exchange sites and happen to see few proposals based entirely on language. For example:

1. [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese)
2. [Stack Overflow in German](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54232/stack-overflow-in-german)
3. [Stack Overflow in Russian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish)
4. [Stack Overflow in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish)

I think there will be many more. I did not go through all the language-specific proposals. Here is my concern:

The criteria required to make a site live (Proposals -> Commits -> Beta -> Live) will get easily matched for such proposals considering there will be a lot of SO users who speak a particular language and are likely to communicate/involve on SO in their native language only.

So there will be quite high chances that a person who is currently quite active on Stack Overflow and speaks (say Russian and English) will be more active on stackoverflow.com/russian_version and will likely to stop involve on English version in the longer run.

- Same questions will be asked again and again in multiple languages
- It will not make sense to share a link to an answer from Spanish version to English version of SO even if the answer is already present in Spanish version.
- A famous question in English can be asked again in different language to gain more upvotes.

I believe this is really a big problem and should be well thought before making such sites live.

PS: Please do not take my question personally as I am not opposed to any country/language. I am just concerned about the quality of Stack Overflow in the future along with the existence of language-specific sites.

Comment: In case you didn't know/realize yet, the [Portuguese Stack Overflow](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) is already in beta.

Comment: @FEichinger Yep..I saw that. I already visited it and translated the page in Chrome and saw few questions which raised the concern in me

Comment: And there are http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187805/should-spanish-so-and-all-the-similar-variants-be-closed and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area-51 which discuss similar topics.

Comment: And this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222511/why-do-we-need-a-stack-overflow-in-portuguese

Comment: I just do not want to split developer community. I did not realize there has already been a discussion around it.That's nice

Comment: You are assuming that the developer community on Stack Overflow will get fragmented. We are thinking that we are empowering people who otherwise wouldn't be able to be part of the community (ie. those developers who do not have a good command of English).