# How do I propose a new site in a local language?

Tags: support, area-51, languages, localization

I know how to propose a new SE site on Area 51, but is there any way I can propose a new site in my local language?

Comment: If you mean another localized SO, IIRC they don't happen to make more of those anymore.

Comment: @Rubisco no not another SO, A new site belongs in Cultural category

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those sites go through the exact same process as any other site, generally with "(in Japanese)" or whatever language appended to the proposal title.

However, **we are not currently accepting new proposals for sites in languages other than English.** Whenever we reach the point where we're willing to start accepting such proposals again, you will see an announcement on either Area 51 Discussions or our network blog.

Answer (score -4):

You can ask a site if it is English, but it accepts non-English questions as well. It is also possible to suggest a new site about a language, where questions on this language are also allowed.

Non-English Stack Overflow clones are currently forbidden, particularly the simple killing of the pretty ready German Stack Overflow proposal (by @TimPost) cries to the sky. Nobody knows its real reason, although I've heard already various rumors and hyphotheses. My personal, subjective impression is that it was rather a central decision and not a single-sided action from a CM; the CMs are only representing this as part of their job.

Unfortunately, considering that it is their site and their company, I don't think we could do anything with it. The [invisible hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invisible_hand) will solve finally this problem.

The language of the meta should go on English, and your chances are higher if you mention this in the proposal (or in the relevant discuss Area 51 posts).

The main problem what I can see that monthly around two proposals can be really started, it seems the Area 51 isn't enough well known until now.

---

In short:

1. You *can't* suggest a StackOverflow on language X.
2. You *can't* suggest a non-English clone of any existing StackExchange site on language X.
3. You *can* suggest a new site about language X.
4. You *can* suggest a new site about country/culture X.

The accepted languages of the main site should be X AND English. The language of the Meta should be mainly English. In your place I would prefer English also in the Area51 proposal:

1. it helps the cooperation with the Area51 decision-makers,
2. you will have sympathisers also from the people not speaking language X, but liking the language/country/culture X.

Comment: I'm sorry, but is this answer true in any way? I see it has a -4 score, but I also see that it's been a year since it was posted and it has not been removed, so maybe what it says is true and the downvotes are just because of certain remarks? Honest question.

Comment: @walen The downvotes are mainly because the answer has a critical tone against the SE policies and customs. The community can vote for an answer on any reason, but the removal of an answer requires a reason. Thus, this answer was voted down, but it wasn't deleted. (P.s. you are lucky that at least a Spanish SO was allowed. The German SO was killed in highly dubious circumstances.) There is another reason of the downvotes in my case: I posted many posts critical against the SE, the communities on different SE sites, and specifically against the community of this site.

Comment: So it is true that you _can_ ask for a stack about a non-English language / country / culture, as long as the stack itself is in English, right?

Comment: @walen Yes, but on the main site, you can allow non-English questions, too. In practice, in the case of not very new sites, also the majority of the meta is going on non-English (see, for example, https://german.meta.stackexchange.com ). The rationale behind that is, that English-only CMs should be able to understand the meta communication. But they are not very active if the site community is already enough strong.

Comment: (I can see how 450 million of Spanish speakers and their low average English level could be a reason for SO.es to be allowed to exist, so as to not lose potential users. I myself have a rather decent English level, so I don't really use SO.es. I can also see how other communities with lower population and higher average English level could be forbidden on the same grounds to avoid detracting users from the main SO site. As you said: their company, their reasons).

Comment: Ok peterh, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @walen Germans are good in English, but not all of them, not even their programmers. And what is more important: many of them don't like it. But they would take part gladly in a German site. These US-only decision makers simply don't understand it. They may have seen some stats, but that was all. To me, it is a very clear sign of their incompetence, and it is not the first one what I see. (P.s. I am not a German and German is not my first language. I only tried to support the German SO A51 proposal, because I like the language.)